# Tomcat remembers classes from the previous session

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, model-view-controller, tomcat9

I'm doing some tutorial Java Spring MVC project in Eclipse.
As a project I've choose Dynamic Web Project.
I have got properly installed Tomcat v9.0.26 and Eclipse 4.13.0.

When I put some modification to my project structure, add new class etc. Tomcat very often doesn't notice any change and it runs exactly the same  like in earlier session.
For example: I had a `SillyController` class just to check that two controller classes cannot have the same `@RequestMapping("something")`.
When I tried execute - Error 500 appears and that was fine because I was testing that.
Now I've deleted `SillyController` class, but the same error appears with the same logs and exception which point to `SillyController` as a root cause.

Every time when I put modification I stop Tomcat Manually, Clean it and Clean Tomcat Work Directory (as shown below). Alsto Rebuild and Save modified project.

[image]
And it doesn't work.
Even restarting Eclipse or turning off Tomcat via terminal (I'm Ubuntu user) doesn't help.

What is strange- sometimes when I had the same situation I just went through and did next step of application and suddenly Tomcat "loaded" last working version of project.

I'm just thinking does it have any cache or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How do you build the application? Via Eclipse, Maven, Gradle? If Eclipse, have you cleaned up the project (not Tomcat dir) and rebuilt it?

Comment: I build an application via Eclipse but I don't use Maven or Gradle. I added Spring files manually and added them to the library. I didn't clean my project, only rebuilding. That is strange, but sometimes (as now) rebuilding project helps and sometimes not.

Comment: I suppose you have not rebuilt the project and after cleaning Tomcat the old (not recompiled) code was deployed, that contained the old .class whose source you modified/deleted. You can activate automatic build in Eclipse. Each time you save changes the relevant classes will be automatically rebuilt. Or just clean and rebuild the project each time before deploying it to the Tomcat. If you have hundreds of classes, the latter can take some time.

Comment: *some tutorial Java Spring MVC project*: You're following obsolete tutorials. Modern Spring applications use Spring Boot and don't require an external container, which takes care of this sort of problem.

Comment: @mentallurg Thank you for your answer, I will turn on "auto rebuilding" and check results. I will inform if problem will appear again.

Comment: @chrylis Good point and good to know. About course - In further parts of course is spring boot, so for now just basics.

Comment: @EnGoPy This is a common misunderstanding. This obsolete style is not "the basics", it is simply not used anymore and not relevant. There is almost no value in being familiar with it unless you are maintaining very old software.

Comment: @chrylis ahhh.... good to know, but quite sad about wasting time. Thank's for a tip